# Is there a way to disable touches on a built-in Widget while still accepting touches on it's child Widget(s)?

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to disable touches on a Flutter Widget, while simultaneously allowing touches on certain children? I'm aware of the `IgnorePointer` and `AbsorbPointer` widgets, but those affect all of the widget subtree. I've run into this issue a few times now, but specifically again in the following case: there's an `ExpansionTile` that I would like to lock open, while still allowing it's children to be clicked. Currently, the built-in Flutter Widget doesn't allow this. You *can* programmatically set the initial state of the `ExpansionTile` to open, but there's no way to lock it that way. I've tried wrapping the `ExpansionTile` in an `AbsorbPointer`, which keeps users from being able to open/close the tile, but it also disables all touch events on the `children` of the `ExpansionTile` (which I want to click on).

To reiterate succinctly: is there a way of disabling touches on a `Widget` while simultaneously allowing touch events on its `children`?

Comment: Is this `ExpansionTile` always open? If yes, why not just use a `Column`?

Comment: since we cant override or extends its `build()` method in private class `_ExpansionTileState` and put the AbsorbPointer to top of `ListTile` inside of `_buildChildren` method, the last thing i will do is copy the entire code from `ExpansionTile` and write it my self. i dont know why they make a built in widget state private

Comment: @rickimaru, because we need the styling of the `ExpansionTile`, and also because there's a list of `ExpansionTile`s, where each one is conditionally locked open or not, depending on what content is inside of it.

Comment: @SayyidJ, I considered doing that, but decided against it because then we wouldn't be getting "updates" to that Widget moving forward, if the Flutter team ever updates it. Copy-pasting the Flutter code and modifying it will obviously essentially "freeze" the code forever. At the end of the day though, we might have to do this if there's not other option. 

Comment: For anyone interested in the specific `ExpansionTile` issue: I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/135770) on the Flutter repo.